# Add thread name to a list of threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am currently working on this exercise where I have to add the names of the thread to the list. This exercise is form-based, so using windows forms app. Every time the user presses the start button a new thread will start at the same time the name of the thread should be added to the list, where name assignment of each thread running is 1,2,3,4... and so on.

But every time I do it using a for loop, it is giving me an error 'INDEX OUT OF BOUND' what am I doing wrong? Can someone please help?

**Update**

Basically this exercise is parameterized and needs to draw circles every time a user presses the start button. I made my list global.

```
List <Thread> _threadName = new List <Thread>();
private void UI_btnStartThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      //create new thread and the referenced the method
      Thread circleThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DrawCircle));

      //the data is passed to the thread as an argument
     circleThread.Start(new AddCircle(_cDrawer, Color.FromArgb(_mainRandom.Next(0, 256), _mainRandom.Next(0, 256), _mainRandom.Next(0, 256)), _circleSize));

     for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
     {
          circleThread.Name = i.ToString();
          //assigning to list
          _threadName[i] = circleThread;
     }
}
```

Comment: can you share you code?

Comment: yes shared as ans

Comment: What data type is `_threadName`? Is it a `string[]`?

Comment: the data type is Thread

Comment: No it isn't. Your code wouldn't compile. It has to be a collection, array, or something else with an indexed property. Please amend your example to include the code that declares the variable `_threadName`.

Comment: yes, now it is giving me an error saying 'Thread name has already been set and cannot be modified'

Comment: In your code example, you are attempting to set the thread's name five times. It can only be set once. Get rid of the loop; you don't need it here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there are a few problems. First of all, it sounds like `_threadName` doesn't have enough elements to handle the range of `i`. You could avoid the issue by using a `List<Thread>` instead of `Thread[]`, since it will grow as needed.

Second, you are updating every element in the list with the latest thread's information. I think you only want to append to the list, keeping any existing values and adding the new thread.

```
private List<Thread> _threads = new List<Thread>();

private void UI_btnStartThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create new thread and the referenced the method
   Thread newThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DrawCircle));

   //the data is passed to the thread as an argument
   newThread.Start(new AddCircle(_cDrawer, Color.FromArgb(_mainRandom.Next(0, 256), _mainRandom.Next(0, 256), _mainRandom.Next(0, 256)), _circleSize));

    _threads.Add(newThread);
}
```

If you are required by your instructor to use an array, you will have to keep track of the number of threads that have already been stored:

```
private Thread[] _threads = new Thread[100];
private int _threadCount = 0;

private void UI_btnStartThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create new thread and the referenced the method
   Thread newThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DrawCircle));

   //the data is passed to the thread as an argument
   newThread.Start(new AddCircle(_cDrawer, Color.FromArgb(_mainRandom.Next(0, 256), _mainRandom.Next(0, 256), _mainRandom.Next(0, 256)), _circleSize));

    _threads[_threadCount++] = newThread;
}
```

Comment: i tried using array but it is giving me an exception 'INDEX OUT OF BOUND'

Comment: @denise - Index out of bound will happen when you access an index outside the size of the array. That is if array is size 10 -- and you try to access arr[10] -- which is 11th Item. Remember arrays start from 0 index.

Answer (score 0):

Few things that you are doing wrong. On Button Click -- You spawn 1 thread

```
Thread circleThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DrawCircle));

            //the data is passed to the thread as an argument
            circleThread.Start(new AddCircle(_cDrawer, Color.FromArgb(_mainRandom.Next(0, 256), _mainRandom.Next(0, 256), _mainRandom.Next(0, 256)), _circleSize));
```

But then you Loop 4 times and Rename the same Thread and add it to the _threadName collection (Array).

```
for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
{
  circleThread.Name = i.ToString();
  //assigning to list
 _threadName[i] = circleThread;
}
```

Rather Do this (Sample code -- written here directly):

In the Form1 Class

```
 List<Thread> _AllThreads = new List<Thread>(); // This will hold ref to all threads you create
```

Next in the Button Click Event:

```
private void UI_btnStartThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Thread myThrd = new Thread(......)
     myThrd.Name = _AllThreads.Count + 1;
     // Start the Thread here

     _AllThreads.Add(myThrd);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Basically this exercise is parameterized and needs to draw circles every time a user presses the start button. I made my list global.**

```
private void UI_btnStartThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //create new thread and the referenced the method
            Thread circleThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DrawCircle));

            //the data is passed to the thread as an argument
            circleThread.Start(new AddCircle(_cDrawer, Color.FromArgb(_mainRandom.Next(0, 256), _mainRandom.Next(0, 256), _mainRandom.Next(0, 256)), _circleSize));

            for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
            {
                circleThread.Name = i.ToString();
                 //assigning to list
                _threadName[i] = circleThread;
            }
        }
```